# graticule for wms layer in Geoserver 2.25 rc version

Tags: geoserver

How to utilise Graticules for WMS maps in geoserver 2.25 rc, I am unable to locate the plugin in community section to install in my geoserver 2.25rc. I have also searched for it in geoserver -2.25 nighty. Beside this after installing the pluggin in my local Geoserver 2.25 how to proceed with it. like data to utilised and further processing, can it be used as a wms layer in openlayers.

I have tried searching for Geoserver plugin to facilitate graticule for wms layer functionality in geoserver 2.25, but I could not find respective plugin , and I am expecting publishing the layer with graticules and operating it in openlayers.

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/478510/79